# .tex files not compiling after brand new installation of TEX live

Tags: compiling

I just updated (from scratch) my OS (from Ubuntu 16 to 18.04). This requires a brand new installation of all apps including Tex Live and the Latex editor (Texmaker in my case). My problem is that none of my .tex files is compiling now. I get an infinite list of errors most which start by "!Undefined sequence ..." error (which makes me think something is missing in my installation). I haven't found any answer here or anywhere else for that matter. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like it is using a default subset of tex commands, so need to check from command line the usual troubleshooting what versioning does LaTeX -version give is it the expected latest or an older default tex, what did you install latex-full ?  running minimal example what is first error from example.log ? what shell directives after install etc.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. I did a mistake when installing my new Ubuntu: change the name of the home which I invoke in the preamble of my files. I will have to update this line for every file.